# How to force all connections to my Apache server to use TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2?

Tags: tls, apache, openssl

I tested on Ubuntu 12.04 (apache 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4 and openssl 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.10) and Ubuntu 13.04 (apache 2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1 and openssl 1.0.1c-4ubuntu8.1).

[here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol) explain how to do so, but I have the following problems:

When try to use:

> SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1

I got the following error:

> [error] No SSL protocols available [hint: SSLProtocol]

when try to use:

> SSLProtocol TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2

I got the following error:

> [error] No SSL protocols available [hint: SSLProtocol]

Th funny thing is that when I use:

> SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -TLSv1

apache don't complain and [this test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) reported that my server not support SSLv2 and TLSv1.0, but yes SSLv3, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2.

Any explanation to that odd behavior? maybe the test tool is broken?

How can I enable just TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2?

Comment: What are your SSLCipherSuite settings?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RodMacPherson `SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 \
EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 \
EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"` as recommended [here](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/08/05/configuring-apache-nginx-and-openssl-for-forward-secrecy#Apache).

Answer (score 5):

(This is a software configuration issue, I sense a relocation to superuser.se coming up...)

There are two pre-requisites for this configuration to work:

- Openssl-1.0.1 (yes)
- httpd-2.2.23 (no!)

Sadly, the [`SSLProtocol`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol) documentation doesn't state the require httpd version (though it is noted in the comments section, right at the bottom of the page).

The code is a little convoluted: it iterates over the list of protocols it's aware of, and eliminates those that you didn't enable. This explains the behaviour you see.

The code up to and including httpd-2.2.22 does not parse "TLSv1.1" or later (see `modules/ssl/ssl_engine_init.c` and `modules/ssl/ssl_private.h`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mr.spuratic I think I found a way to disable *TLSv1.0* and *TLSv1.1*: Setting `SSLCipherSuite` with just ciphers that are supported in *TLSv1.2*.

Comment: Could you share your solution?

Comment: You could list the TLSv1.2 ciphers one by one (start with `openssl ciphers -v | grep v1.2`) or start with something like `AESGCM:SHA384:SHA256:!aNULL:!eNULL:!DSS` and tweak it as required. This effectively rejects <TLSv1.2 clients by requiring the newest ciphers/MACs. The downsides are that clients using an older protocol will fail with a misleading error ("no shared cipher" or handshake failure, instead of "wrong TLS version"), and you cannot support older multi-version ciphers at all, like AES128-SHA. So just upgrade already ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Setting *SSLCipherSuite* with just ciphers that are **JUST** supported in *TLSv1.2* bypass the Apache 2.2 limitation of parse *TLSv1.1* string that @mr.spuratic talk about.

Answer (score 1):

The openssl in ubuntu does not support TLSv1.2, They have disabled it.
It is documented in 
[bug 1256576](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1256576)

Comment: No, they only disabled TLS1.2 on the client side, not on the server side. And this is probably done because it broke things with older F5 devices. 1.0.1g now has a workaround for this which then breaks IronPort. Having fun with TLS today?

Comment: Yep, You are right. They at that time enabled TLS1.2 on server side only. Had a hard time figuring out a break in a lib which share some code for both server and client.